# Link Files from Directory to directory

Tags: php, include, subdirectory

> rootFolder

**index.php**

**cssFolder**
             fontAwesomeFolder
             -main.css
             -tablet.css

**imagesFolder**
             -image.jpg

**includesFolder**
             -navMain.php
             -footer.php

**pagesFolder**
             -contactUs.php

**jsFolder**
             -core.js

I have topology here about my website. Thing is, when I tried to link/include **navMain.php** in the **includesFolder** to the **contactUs.php** in the **pageFolder**, some other links are messed-up, particularly - css and images files. They don't seems to work.

The issue is the PHP INCLUDE. Alright. It works fine with the index.php. But not with the file in the subdirectories.

How am I going to bring this around. Some said, I'd use config.php. I tried, didn't work. If ever I'm going to use Config.php, what exact codes do I have to place in there and what codes to the other documents.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try to include some of your code.

Comment: contactUs.php and navMain.php have no codes yet. Nevertheless, in my index.php file this is how I arrange my codes:  <?php require_once "navMain.php" ?>  - that simple. And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your assets urls are relative to your file location. To avoid this you can always use `/` to make them relative to your root url and avoid getting `404` errors:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cssFolder/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cssFolder/tablet.css" />
```

Comment: This is good! In fact I use this a lot in the landing page or home page. Nevertheless, in the pages within the subfolders, I guess it requires more tweaking.